# How to wrap the figure texture in php or js?

Tags: javascript, php, image

i have task. We have base image (kitchen), and texture. How How to wrap the figure (table in kitchen) texture.

[image: Example result]

Comment: You want to use the texture on different places in this picture?

Comment: Yes, you see tabletop in image, i need chage this texture depending on the choice of texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a png of this image and make the tabletops transparent. Then you can change the css background image so the correct texture appears.

```
<div style="background-image:url('texture.jpg')">
     <img src="kitchen.png" />
</div>
```